# Export row-wise colored dataframe to excel using pandas styler

Tags: dataframe, colors, conditional-statements, rows, background-color

I have some trouble with using Pandas Style. Actually I try to color rows in a dataFrame if a certain column contain a certain value. And at the End I want to put the colored df in an Excelfile.
thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I solve it :) Style1 = df_table1.style.apply(lambda x: ["background-color: yellow" if x in df_table2["Col1"].values else "" for x in df_table1["Col2"]]).                                 
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:
    Style1.to_excel(writer)Thanks !